# Auto re-link tables (VBA) in Acces from MariaDB via ODBC

Tags: vba, ms-access, mariadb

I need to re-link tables in VBA from MariaDB SQL via ODBC to Access. I found some code below, but it doesn't work. When I run it its nothing happens.

Re-link is needed when in SQL I add some column it doesn't appears in Access. 
When I do manual Table re-link it appears.

This code was for Postgresql, not for MariaDB. Perhaps it's need some corrections...

```
Sub refreshLinked_MariaDB()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    For Each tbd In cdb.TableDefs
        If tbd.Connect Like "ODBC;Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver*" Then
            Debug.Print "Refreshing [" & tbd.Name & "] ..."
            tbd.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done."
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Update: After `if` function edit re-link works fine, but some of tables become "Read-only", that means I can't add or edit any records. After deleting these tables and link manual - works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Are these executed: `Debug.Print "Refreshing..`? Ctrl+G shows the output. 2. Are the new columns visible after Compact&Repair? Then you may need `cdb.TableDefs.Refresh` at the end.

Comment: When press CTRL+G and run code output shows only "Done." After Compact&Repair new column still doesnt visible.

Comment: Then add `Debug.Print tbd.Connect` after `For Each`. Your `If` condition seems to be wrong.

Comment: Debug shows `ODBC;DSN=Access -> MariaDB`. 
"Access -> MariaDB" is my ODBC connection name. Should `If` condition must look like: `If tbd.Connect Like "ODBC;DSN=Access -> MariaDB" Then` ? I'm tried but nothing.

Comment: I changed `If` function to `If left(tbd.Connect,5) = "ODBC;" then` and its works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: One more insue.. Several re-linked tables become "Read-only" after this re-link, that means I can't change or add any data in this table from access. When I re-link it manual everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your connection string is different and the filter doesn't recognize it as Maria DB. Alternatively, you can try changing

```
If tbd.Connect Like "ODBC;Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver*" Then
```

To

```
If left(tbd.Connect,5) = "ODBC;" then
```

Also note that **like** in VBA is different from the **like*" in sql